# Dados do datagridview passando de uma tela para outra

Tags: c#, sql-server

Boa tarde, tenho uns dados que carregam um datagridview, estes dados vem de uma query no banco de dados no slq, e nesse datagrid tenho uma coluna com um chekbox, queria saber como faço par quando o usuário ticar no chekbox na linha e esta linha ticada aparecer em outra tela, e possível fazer isso e se sim como posso fazer isso?

segue imagem que carrega o datagrid com o chekbox
esqueça o erro na imagem já foi ajustado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue o codigo que carrega a tela

```
 private void ListaGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand separacao = new SqlCommand("usp_SeparacaoPic", conexaoDADOADV(true));
            separacao.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            separacao.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(separacao);
            DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
            dados.Fill(dtLista);

            dgw_separacaopic.DataSource = dtLista;

            dgw_separacaopic.Columns["CLIENTE"].ReadOnly = true;
            dgw_separacaopic.Columns["PRODUTO"].ReadOnly = true;
            dgw_separacaopic.Columns["LOTE"].ReadOnly = true;
            dgw_separacaopic.Columns["PEDIDO"].ReadOnly = true;
            dgw_separacaopic.Columns["LIBERACAO"].ReadOnly = true;
            dgw_separacaopic.Columns["ITEM"].ReadOnly = true;
            dgw_separacaopic.Columns["QTDA"].ReadOnly = true;
            dgw_separacaopic.Columns["ESTOQUE"].ReadOnly = true;
            dgw_separacaopic.Columns["OBS"].ReadOnly = true;

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Não exstem dados digitados para a consulta, por favor verificar!!!");
            return;
        }
    }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (Int32 index = 0; index < dgw_separacaopic.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            if (bool.Parse(dgw_separacaopic.Rows[index].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString()) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("teste");
            }

        }
    }
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Mas essa linha irá aparecer onde? em outro DataGrid? ou preenchendo `textbox` em outro form? explique um pouco melhor

Comment: Desculpe a falta de informação, preciso que a linha selecionada apareça em outro grid, e quando selecionar travar a edição o chekbox para não mexer mais. Já consegui verificar a linha se esta selecionada ou não, só preciso que leve as informações para outro grid.

Comment: PHP então nesse exemplo não ficou muito claro o que eu faço no segundo form onde tenho o outro datagrid, por não mencionei acim que os grids estão em forms diferentes.